# iTerm2 doesn't read com.googlecode.iterm2.plist

Tags: macos, iterm, python, plist

I am iTerm2 (1.0.0) user. I know how to create profiles, by using iTerm settings or modifying `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` file.

For convenience, I will use `.plist` to indicate `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` file.

There are some profiles already to connect my dev server using a command. (i.e. `ssh 192.168.1.1`).

I want to modify and add more profiles to iTerm. So, I wrote a Python script to do this. The procedure is like below.

1. Convert iTerm2 `.plist` file to `.xml`. (i.e. `plutil -convert xml1`)
2. Write several profiles to this file using `plistlib` in Python.
3. Convert iTerm2 `.plist` file to binary format that as it was. (i.e. `plutil -convert binary1`)

The procedure above doesn't work. iTerm2 didn't load my profiles created from my Python script.

So, I checked if there is no `.plist` file, how iTerm load the profiles.

1. I quit the iTerm2 program.
2. I deleted the `.plist` file from my disk, which is located at `~/Library/Preferences/`.
3. Run iTerm2 program.
4. open Profile Setting by typing <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

I found there are profiles even if I deleted the `.plist` file. What happened here? Is there any backup profiles file which I don't recognize?

Comment: Thanks 'Jawa' for editing my posting to be more good looking. :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Preferences are cached in 10.9. See http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130908042828630. If you edit a plist file directly or replace the plist of an application, the application will keep using the cached version even after you quit and reopen the application.

You can run `defaults read com.googlecode.iterm2` or `killall cfprefsd` to apply the changes:

1. Quit iTerm
2. Edit the plist
3. Run `defaults read com.googlecode.iterm2` or `killall cfprefsd`
4. Open iTerm

Changes made with `defaults` are applied after you just quit and reopen an application like in earlier versions of OS X.

---

Comment: That's great, this is what I found. Thanks a lot. And I am sorry posting duplicated question, I didn't know where I have to post this stuffs. And I am enjoying my iTerm. :)

Answer (score 16):

Having great trouble migrating iTerm2 (2.0.0) plist to my new Mac running Yosemite (10.10.1). What I did to fix that is:

1. Open iTerm2, so a default `com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` file is created.
2. Quit iTerm2
3. Deleted all cached preferences for iterm2 by issuing `defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2`
4. Copied the file to the new Mac in the correct location inside Preferences folder, so I had my old profiles and settings back
5. Read in the prefs file with `defaults read -app iTerm`
6. Open iTerm2 and was happy to have profiles and window arrangements on my new Mac

Comment: Thanks this worked. One more requirement I found out the hard way is that the iTerm version of the saved profile should match the version of the current iTerm (where you're migrating to).

Comment: Thanks for for the `defaults read -app`, I was looking for a way to read any app's prefs file and didn't know how!