# Restoring iTerm2 to default values

Tags: applications, preferences, iterm, macos

I installed iTerm2, played a bit with the preferences.

Now I would go back to the initial configuration, but removing the app and finding and removing any file on the disk apparently related to the app does not help: after reinstalling, the preferences are still the modified ones.

Comment: How did you remove the related files?  Besides the Library/Preferences/ directory, there may also be something saved in Library/Preferences/ByHost/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I found the answer in [iTerm FAQs :: Where does iTerm2 store its settings?](http://iterm2.com/faq.html):

```
defaults delete com.googlecode.iterm2
```

Comment: Adding the FAQ Link would be good, for future searchers

Comment: Maybe you also need to execute `killall cfprefsd´ - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111534/iterm2-doesnt-read-com-googlecode-iterm2-plist

Comment: @Tetsujin: done.

Comment: This appears to be out-dated information as that key no longer appears in `defaults`.

Comment: @Allen I just tested it on iTerm build 3.3.6 and it worked fine