# iTerm2 preferences keep resetting after reboot

Tags: macos, preferences, iterm, plist

My changes to the preferences in [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com) are always reset after a reboot. They will survive a logout, but after a reboot everything is back to the previous state. I checked `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` and my user is file owner and also has write access. Does anybody know how to fix this?

I remember reading that Yosemite is protecting `plist` files somehow. Could this be the cause? I'm on 10.10.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well. I did not find the cause for the issue (although it was quite obviously some file permissions problem). But this is how I fixed it:

1. Quit iterm2
2. Move `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` to the Desktop
3. Reboot (because [plist files are protected](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/111559/45492))
4. Launch iterm2 and quit it again to create a new plist file
5. Open `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` in an editor
6. Paste the contents of the plist file on the Desktop into the new one
7. Reboot

Comment: What if file is not there to start from?